# Using The Google Visualisation API to Overlay a Bar Chart On Top Of A Line Chart

Tags: java, charts, google-visualization

Hello
Does anyone know if it's possible to use the [Google Visualisation API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) (in a Java program) to plot a graph consisting of a bar chart overlayed on top of a Line chart. Why would anyone want to do this you might ask? Well, I have some [day trading signals](http://moneycashcurrency.com/wp/mcc/forex-day-trading-signals) I would like to plot. I'm currently using [JFreechart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) to plot trading signals but it's not very well documented which kinda means you're on your own when you try to do anything that strays from the beaten path.

Thanks  in advance

PS: Sorry if my site is slow for you but this is due to the fact that it's hosted on an [Amazon EC2 Micro Instance](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#instance) which gets [severely throttled](http://gregsramblings.com/2011/02/07/amazon-ec2-micro-instance-cpu-steal/) whenever traffic spikes (read Google crawls the pages) occur. Please be patient when you click on the link the chart will load.... eventually 10 seconds

Answer (score 2):

Google image chart tools can do this, but it will be a static chart (no interactive data points).
Try this:

```
cht=bvg
chs=250x150
chxt=x,y
chd=t1:30,10,20,50,90|60,40,50,30
chm=D,000000,1,0,5,1
```

here:
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/chart_playground.html

There are a bunch of docs, and you should be able to generate the required URL in any language.

UPDATE:

I was incorrect; looks like [Combo Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart.html) was recently added to the js API. Does this do what you need?